# the server could not find the request resource sharepoint designer 2013 Sharepoint online url

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, office-365

[image]

When i am trying to open SharePoint Online url using SharePoint designer2013 it is popping up error message.

I have full access on site collection level still i am not able to open.
Please help me on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to `Site Settings >> Master pages and page layouts`
  OR simply hit https://MySiteURL/_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx URL and check if have appropriate permissions on this library

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Clear SharePoint designer cache.
2. Uninstall and re-install SharePoint designer.
3. Create a new site in SharePoint online and check if the site can be opened in SharePoint designer.

More reference:

[How to Clear Your SharePoint Designer 2010/2013 Cache.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-20102013-cache/)